# How to save a state of a Switch in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode6

How can I save a single variable (in my case a Boolean true/false flag) in a Core Data model.

So far I did the following:

1. Entity called MyBooleanFlag
2. Added Attribute called myAttribute with a Type 'Boolean'

How can I easily store permamently a state of a Switch in the Core Data?

Probably the next step would be to load this Core Data value, when the viewcontroller is loaded.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you need to use CoreData?  If you have only the state of one switch to save, you might use `NSUserDefaults` instead.

Comment: What is the purpose of this switch? is there only one? saving it to NSUserDefaults may be an option as well. Otherwise, you'd need to instantiate your managedObjectModel class and set its myAttribute property to the state of the switch, and then save it to your persistent store coordinator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to save a user preference? If so, `NSUserDefaults` is likely a far better choice than Core Data.

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/storing-data-with-nsuserdefaults/
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that there is a much simpler solution.